# malloc 48 bytes Memory leak in allocating the memory not getting any solution

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, memory-leaks

i am working with an application in which i am receiving the memory allocation leak like malloc 48 bytes in strdup frame and i have searched alot but did not find any solution and i am attaching a screenshot of instruments memory leak.
Please help me if any one knows solution and my xcode version is 4.3.3 and ios 5.1.1.[image: image of instruments]

Comment: Is this 48 bytes leaked once per running of the program, or 48 bytes leaked hundreds of times? If its once per running of the app, it may be something you can't or don't need to bother fixing.

Comment: Open the Extended Detail panel to see the stack trace of the call to malloc.

Answer (score 1):

It's a known bug present in iOS at the moment relating to UIScrollViews. All you can do at the moment is wait for a system update and hope that it is fixed.

Here is some more information: http://openradar.appspot.com/11081198

Comment: i am not getting this issue in UIScrollView. I got it in the actionSheet:clickedbuttonAtIndex when calling these lines picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
   [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];